# How do I use chdir to traverse subdirectories and parse XML files?

Tags: perl

I want to write a script that traverses a directory and its subdirectories, grabs all the XML files and parses them. I am having trouble with `chdir`. This works fine:

```
my $search = "/home/user/books";
chdir($search) or die "cant change dir to $search $!";
system("ls");
```

But I want the user to decide the path where he want to search it so I am using `Getopt::Long`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use Getopt::Long;

my $outputFile = '';
my $searchPath = "";
my $debug      = 0;
GetOptions('outputFile=s' => \$outputFile, 'searchPath=s' => \$searchPath);
if ($outputFile eq '' or $searchPath = '') {
    die("parameter --outpulFile=s is required.");
}
$searchPath =~ s/\/*$/\//;
my @founddirs = `cd $searchPath`;
foreach my $foundfiles (@founddirs) {
    print $foundfiles;
    chdir($foundfiles) or die "cant change dir to $searchPath $!";
    chdir('..');
}
```

Command to run:

```
perl sample.pl --outputFile=books.txt --searchPath=/home/user/june18
```

I want to grab all the recursive.xml files from the subdirectories and parse them. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Why doesn't your code work?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: yes it says Can't exec "cd": No such file or directory at sample.pl line 20.

Comment: I just tried adding  my @founddirs = `cd $searchPath;ls`; and now it says "cant change directory to / no such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues here:

- `$searchPath = ''` is setting the search path to an empty string during the input validation. Use `eq` instead (not `==`)
- `@founddirs` will contain nothing since the backtick operator will return nothing. This is because

  ```
  my @founddirs = `cd $searchPath`;
  ```

  does not print found directories that are separated by newlines. Perhaps you're after `ls $searchPath`

On a side note, why not use `File::Find` instead?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use Getopt::Long;

my $outputFile;
my $searchPath;

GetOptions(
            'outputFile=s' => \$outputFile,
            'searchPath=s' => \$searchPath,
          );

die "Usage : perl sample.pl -outputFile -searchPath\n"
  unless $outputFile && $searchPath;

die "No such directory found: $searchPath\n" unless -d $searchPath;

find( sub { print "$File::Find::name\n" if /$outputFile/ }, $searchPath );
```

Comment: yes i tried using ls but it is keep printing the root directory folders. so how could i still keep the searchPath Parameter by user input and use file::Find ? 

I am new to perl.

Comment: tried the sample code but not getting anything at all as a result?

Comment: @upstream : What was your test?

Comment: i did not get anything in return. neither it created the $outputFile.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw/ dd /;
use File::Find::Rule qw/ find /;
my @files = find(
    file =>
    name => '*.xml',
    in => \@ARGV
);

dd \@files;

__END__
$ perl ffrule
[]

$ perl ffrule ../soap
[
 "../soap/ex1.xml",
 "../soap/ex2.xml",
 "../soap/ex3.xml",
]
```